# Mod Rewrite Rule to Rewrite URL Parameters Throughout Site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to just mod rewrite just a parameter and have it apply to all pages?

I have a parameter called `coords` that's used throughout my site. Its the decimal latitude, followed by a comma, and followed by the decimal longitude. However, sometimes people put a space after the comma if they copy and paste the coordinates from places like Google Maps.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
RewriteRule coords=(-?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]*)?,)( |%20|+)?(-?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]*)?,) coords=$1$4 [L,R=301]
```

And have it modify requests like:

- https://bluewidget.tld/?cords=37.818631, -122.478474
- https://bluewidget.tld/?x=1&cords=38.624553, -90.185041
- https://bluewidget.tld/page.html?cords=43.722985, 10.396634
- https://bluewidget.tld/page.html?x=1&cords=39.916442, 116.390775&y=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*coords=-?\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?,)(?:\s+|\%20|\+)(-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?,?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```